# can not get $_post["SearchSubmit"] value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

```
<form class="form-inline" id="form1" method="post" role="form" action="">
    <div class="from-group">
        <label for="usr">Search Here</label>
        <input id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="SearchSubmit" value="GO" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
    </div>
</form>
<?php var_dump($_POST['SearchSubmit']); ?>
    <table class="table text-info">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date of Birth</th>
            <th class="text-center">Address</th>
            <th class="text-center">Last Passout Standard</th>
            <th class="text-center">Last Passout Percentage</th>
            <th class="text-center">Last Passout Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="log"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        <?php if($_POST['SearchSubmit']){ ?>
           $('document').ready(function() {
               $('#log').load('searchresult.php');
           });
          //$('#log').load('searchresult.php');
          <?php } ?>
           $('document').ready(function() {
                 $('#log').load('studentList.php');
              });
          //$('#log').load('studentList.php');
    </script>
```

The above mentioned is my code but i can not load any of them log file in my current php page.
I have also print the `$_POST['SearchSubmit']` what i get is null value.
I just want to get if search box is filled so searchresult will be load otherwise studentList will be load.
please help to solve this issue.

Comment: dfk you are mixing php with javascript, why?

Comment: Your php if statement has missing php opening and closing tags

Comment: ohh i got that , im a beginer in php so i did that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

if you use php stick with it

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['SearchSubmit'])){
 include 'searchresult.php';
} else {
 include 'studentList.php';
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything is fine.But you did not assigned action to form.Set same page name as action.Suppose your page name is myform.php. then action="myform.php".

Comment: this is more of a comment then an answer

Comment: Perfectly valid (not valid to w3c, but browsers accept this)